# Como substituir o src de uma tag img?

Tags: javascript, html, imagem

Tenho uma pagina html que mostra uma imagem para cada dia do ano.

As imagens estão organizadas em pastas por exemplo `/img/o1/o1.jpg` (referente ao dia 1 de janeiro) e assim por diante.

O meu html é simples quero que pegue o dia + mês de hoje e substitua no source de uma tag img

Como eu poderia fazer isso ? Javascript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Faça com javascript, coloque um id ou classe para indentificar, resgate com javascript, e altere a propriedade

```
var img = document.getElementById('teste');
img.src = 'teste';
```

desculpe... 
para vc pegar a data ...

```
var d = new Date();
var mes = d.getMonth()+1;
var dia = d.getDate();

/// alterando o src
var newImg = '0'+mes+'/'+dia+'.jpg';
img.src = newImg;
```

Entendeu ?

Comment: E a data entra onde? Teria como mostrar um exemplo?

Comment: Cuidado, javacript pega sempre o valor local da maquina entao se estiver errado a maquina vc vai acabar trazendo imagem errada.

Comment: Ou se seu computador estiver em um fuso horário diferente daquele do servidor (o que pode ser um *bug* ou uma *feature*, dependendo da sua intenção).

Comment: @karmex esse script proposto vai afetar a imagem que estiver com id='teste' no html.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode alterar a propriedade `src` usando um identificador ou algo que possa selecionar na imagem. Então pode recuperar o nó dela com javascript e editar qualquer atributo.

**Exemplo:**

```
var

    // Armazena o nó da imagem.
    image = document.getElementById('id-da-imagem'),

    // Recupera um objeto com o momento atual.
    date = new Date(),

    // Recupera o mês do objeto "date".
    month = date.getMonth(),

    // Recupera o dia do objeto "date".
    day = date.getDate();

// Altera o source da imagem armazenada.
image.src = '/img/' + month + '/' + day + '.jpg';
```

**Caso queira trocar o atributo com jQuery:**

```
var

    // Recupera um objeto com o momento atual.
    date = new Date(),

    // Recupera o mês do objeto "date".
    month = date.getMonth(),

    // Recupera o dia do objeto "date".
    day = date.getDate();

// Altera o source da imagem armazenada.
$('#id-da-imagem').attr('src', '/img/' + (month < 10 ? '0' + month : month) + '/' + (day < 10 ? '0' + day : day) + '.jpg');
```

**Veja este exemplo de aplicação no jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/n28gk/1/

Answer (score 2):

Você pode inserir as imagens na sua página em campos hiddens e fazer a validação que exibiram acima em JS:

```
var

    // Armazena o nó da imagem.
    image = document.getElementById('id-da-imagem'),

    // Recupera um objeto com o momento atual.
    date = new Date(),

    // Recupera o mês do objeto "date".
    month = date.getMonth(),

    // Recupera o dia do objeto "date".
    day = date.getDate();

// Altera o source da imagem armazenada.
image.src = '/img/' + month + '/' + day + '.jpg';
```

Que a partir dai funcionará direitinho!